# How many different countries could a person alive today have lived in without leaving their hometown?

Tags: 20th-century, geography

For example, a centenarian who has spent her entire life in [Rijeka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijeka) would have lived in five:

- The Austro-Hungarian Empire (until 1920)
- The Free State of Fiume (1920-1924)
- Italy (1924-1947)
- Yugoslavia (1947-1991)
- Croatia (1991-present)

Is there any piece of land in the world which has been in more hands than that since March 5, 1898 (the birthdate of the [oldest living person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misao_Okawa))?  If so, where?

Comment: I understand why this was put on hold but consider that in attempting to answer the question, you end up exploring a very interesting maze of historical geopolitics. I know I did. So I personally encourage these quirky historical questions as they often act an [unique lens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_of_chance_in_scientific_discoveries) for viewing the past.

Comment: You will likely find your city in Eastern Europe. For example, [Carpatho-Ukraine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpatho-Ukraine) appears to have been part of A-H, then Czechoslovakia, then declared independent, then Hungary, then Soviet Union, then Ukraine. Of course, it depends on how you define "change of countries" - is Hungary distinct from A-H, is Ukrainian SSR distinct from Ukraine, is Croatia distinct from Yugoslavia?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

I think the Carpathian Ruthenia area (the little triangle on the "end" of Czechoslovakia after the end of WW1) gives us five bona fide separate national entities and more if pseudo-states (such as your Fiume) and other periods of loose or brief control are allowed.

> **up to 1918  Austria-Hungary**
>   *1918 Hungary*
>   *1918          [West Ukraine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Ukrainian_People%27s_Republic)*
>   **1918-1939    Czechoslovakia**
>   *1939           [Carpatho-Ukraine Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Carpatho-Ukraine)*
>   **1939-1944    Hungary**
>   *1944-1945    Czechoslovakia*
>   **1945-1991    USSR**
>   **1991 -        Ukraine**

I've marked in bold where nation states were recognisably exercising full sovereignty over the area. Looser claims in italics.

[Memelland (now Klaipeda)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaip%C4%97da_Region) in Lithuania is another possible candidate.

Comment: Now if you could find some pre-1939 border adjustments between Czechoslovakia or A-H and Poland or Romania...

Comment: @Jørgen yes! we need some small Carpathian town to have been temporarily given to Romania for a few years, perhaps by cartographic oversight or to solve a problem with a road or some such

Answer (score 20):

[Metohija](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metohija)

1. Ottoman Empire (until 1912)
2. Montenegro (1912-1915)
3. Austria-Hungary (1915-1918)
4. Serbia (1918)
5. Kingdom of Serbs, Croats
   and Slovenes (1918–1929)
6. Kingdom of Yugoslavia (1929–1941)
7. Italian protectorate of Albania (1941-1943)
8. Nazi Germany (1943-1944)
9. Serbia (1944-1946)
10. Yugoslavia (1946-1991)
11. Federal Republic of Yugoslavia(1992-2003)
12. Serbia and Montenegro (2003-2006)
13. Serbia (2006-2008)
14. Kosovo (2008-

Answer (score 6):

[Lviv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lviv):

1. Austria-Hungary (until 1918)
2. [Western Ukrainian National Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Ukrainian_People%27s_Republic)
3. Poland (1918-1939)
4. USSR (1939-1941)
5. [Reichskommissariat Ukraine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichskommissariat_Ukraine) (1941-1944)
6. Poland (1944-1946)
7. USSR (1946-1991)
8. Ukraine (1991-now)

This does not qualify as the most number of *different* countries, but probably qualifies as the most number of *changes* in national flag.

Comment: I bet the residents were glad when not in Russia as the Russian winters are so cold.

Answer (score 2):

[Cešký Těšin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cesk%C3%BD_T%C4%9B%C5%A1%C3%ADn), the western part of [Cieszyn, Silesia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cieszyn_Silesia):

- *to 1918*: Austria-Hungary
- October 31-November 5 1918: competing Czech and Polish local administrations
- November 5 1918- Jan 30 1919: Polish occupation
- 1919-1920: Czech occupation
- 1920-1938: First Czechoslovak Republic (formalized by 1920 Spa Conference)
- 1938-1939: Second Polish Republic (Polish occupation after Munich Agreement)
- 1939-1945: Großdeutsches Reich (i.e. annexed by Nazi Germany)
- 1945-1992: Czechoslovakia
- 1993-: Czech Republic/Czechia

Answer (score 1):

[U Sabotů](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0ance_(Vrbovce)), now [Šance](https://sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0ance_(Vrbovce)) (see the [map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/48.8194/17.5034)).

- until 1918: Austria(-Hungary)
- 1918 - 1939 Czechoslovakia
- 1939 - 1945 Germany (Protektorat Böhmen und Mähren)
- 1945 - 1992 Czechoslovakia
- 1993 - 1997 Czech Republic
- 1997 - Slovakia